# VF page error: 'Unknown method' yet method declared in controller

Tags: visualforce

I've a button on VF page that call a delCount() method, declared in the controller, but I get error Unknown method delCount(). How is it possibile?

PAGE

```
  <apex:page Controller="QuotationController" tabstyle="Opportunity" >
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Quotation Template"> 
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Available Starting Template">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ListaQuotation}" var="f">
  <apex:column value="{!f.Name}">   
 </apex:column>  
 <apex:column value="{!f.Q_Product_Consultant_costs__c}">
 </apex:column> 
<apex:column value="{!f.Q_Product_Program_Director_costs__c}">
  </apex:column> 
 <apex:column value="{!f.Q_Product_Project_Manager_costs__c}">
 </apex:column> 
<apex:column value="{!f.Q_Product_Senior_Graphic_Designer_costs__c}">
 </apex:column>   
<apex:column value="{!f.Q_Products_total_costs__c}">
 </apex:column>     
<apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header"<Related Products</apex:facet>

            <ul>
                <apex:repeat value="{!f.Q_Products__r}" var="qp">
                    <li><apex:outputField value="{!qp.Product_Type__c}" /></li>                        
                </apex:repeat>
            </ul>
        </apex:column>    


<apex:column >
<apex:commandButton value="Select" 
                    id="a"
                    onclick="window.open('/{!f.Id}/e?clone=1'); return false;"/> 
  </apex:column>  

  <apex:column headerValue="Action">
  <apex:commandButton value="Del" action="{!delCont}" rerender="all">
   <apex:param name="contIdParam" value="{!f.id}" assignTo="{!contIdChosen}"/>
   </apex:commandButton>
   </apex:column>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

CLASS

```
 public virtual class QuotationController {
 public String contIdChosen {get; set;}
    public PageReference delCont() 
     {
   Quotation__c toDel=new Quotation__c(id=contIdChosen);
  / /Quotation__c newcontact= new Quotation__c();
    //insert newContact;
    delete todel;
    return null;
   }
   public Quotation__c myq {get; set;}
public QuotationController () {
    }
    public List<Quotation__c> getListaQuotation() {
     return [select Id, Name, Q_Product_Consultant_costs__c, Q_Product_Program_Director_costs__c, Q_Products_total_costs__c,
   Q_Product_Project_Manager_costs__C, Q_Product_Senior_Graphic_Designer_costs__c, (SELECT Name, Product_Type__c
    from Q_Products__r)
                     from Quotation__c 
                     WHERE IsTemplate__c = true
                     ];                     

        }


   }
```

Comment: Please post the entire code of the VF page & controller.

Comment: Are you sure there are no type errors or incorrect class name?

Comment: post the complete class code, including the class name, since the issue is not with the method functionality, but rather with the visibility of method itself.

Comment: I'm trying to post all code, please wait :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using a `virtual` class as the controller. Can you give it a try by changing it to `public with sharing class QuotationController{}` ?

Comment: Now I would like to be able to reference all the fields of the record referenced by the contIdChosen. But if I try to reference todel.Name, it's null..

Comment: You will need to issue a select statement to load the record from the DB or use the previously selected list of Quotation__c objects and find the chosen one from there. I'd probably to a 'light load' with only the fields I need to allow a user to choose which record to select and then load all the fields I need once a record has been chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your class definition from `public virtual class QuotationController` into `public with sharing class QuotationController{}`

Comment: thank you. I would have another question. how can I reference the fields of toDel Quotation? I have the id but if I try to reference its name , it will be just null.

Comment: First, if you found this as the answer make sure to mark it as the answer so that other contributors don't waste their time to answering already answered one. Community will give you values for being honest and keeping up the good work. Though it's an another question to be posted I think you are initializing `toDel` with only the `Id` of it as per your code. So none of other fields give you values. If you need to access other fields, when the `toDel` is initializing do it by populating other those fields as well.