# Survey force getting error on method call

Tags: apex, visualforce, survey

```
Error: Unknown method 'Survey__cStandardController.addMoreQuestion()
```

I am customizing the survey force app controller 
     "global virtual with sharing class SurveyAndQuestionController".But,
getting this error on calling addMoreQuestion method from the commandlink tag.
VF page:

```
 <apex:page standardcontroller="Survey__c" extensions="SurveyAndQuestionController" cache="false" sidebar="false" showheader="false" >

<p class="commonAdd addDate add"> 
    <apex:commandlink action="{!addMoreQuestion}" value="{!$Label.Add_Another_Question_Sur}" rendered="{!showFreeText}" / >                                           
</p>
```

Controller:

```
global virtual with sharing class SurveyAndQuestionController{
```

Comment: Can you please post the first line of your page?

Comment: @umithuckan..updated

Comment: is your method also global or not ? (it can be the reason)

Comment: method is public..

Comment: can you please add the VF code of commandLink?

Comment: Can  you adjust it as global an try again.
You probably call it as action={addMoreQuestion} and it lets you save on compile time.So it can be related to this.

Comment: Code updated..@RCS

Comment: @umithuckan..already tried sir.

Comment: Can you post constructor of your controller extension class?

Answer (score 0):

reference to the link:
[VF page error: 'Unknown method' yet method declared in controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40867/vf-page-error-unknown-method-yet-method-declared-in-controller)

remove your virtual anotation from class.

Here is my code and it worked for me.
Let's try to find differences then.

```
global virtual with sharing class testUnknown{
   public void addMoreQuestion(){
      system.debug('it worked..');
   }

public boolean showFreeText {get;Set;}
public Account acct;

   public testUnknown(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
      this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
      showFreeText = true;
   }

}
```

Page

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="testUnknown"  cache="false" sidebar="false" showheader="false" >
<apex:form>
<p class="commonAdd addDate add"> 
<apex:commandlink action="{!addMoreQuestion}" value="test" rendered="{!showFreeText}" / >                                           
</p>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: already tried that link but nothing happened..

Comment: So, you have only one controller which called SurveyAndQuestionController and addMoreQuestion is defined  public in it.It works without parameter.
It has standard controller constructor right?

Comment: Exactly..all things are like this.

Comment: Let me try your code..

Comment: Did it work for you?